# How to alias attributes in XStream with annotations?

Tags: java, spring, xstream

I have the following piece of code

```
@XStreamAlias("Pa")
public class Pa {

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String ms;

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String co;

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String house;

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String street;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

I want my attributes names to be different from the variable names when my XML is constructed.

I know I can do it to classes with the following annotation

```
@XStreamAlias("ExampleClass")
private ExClass exClass;
```

The above code will result in a tag with the name

```
<ExampleClass/>
```

However, I cannot find any annotation that changes the name of the attribute without creating a separate tag.

What I want is the following:

```
<Pa milliseconds="" co =""/>
```

But using

```
@XStreamAlias("Milliseconds")
private String ms;
```

is creating a new tag with the given name. It no longer stays an attribute of the tag.

Does such an annotation exist? I need to do it only using annotations, not at runtime using Java code.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use both annotations:

```
@XStreamAlias("Pa")
public class Pa {

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    @XStreamAlias("Milliseconds")
    String ms = "test";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XStream xStream = new XStream();
        xStream.ignoreUnknownElements();
        xStream.processAnnotations(Pa.class);

        String xml = xStream.toXML(new Pa());
        System.out.println(xml);
    }
}
```

output:

```
<Pa Milliseconds="test"/>
```